Vertical line without `GridLines`
I have the following Mathematica code. I want you to draw a vertical line at π/2, but without using GridLines -> {{Pi/2}, None}, because the line does not appear in the small inset plot.
Clear["Global`*"]
xPos = 1.502;
range = 0.2;
f[x_] := Tan[x];
xyMinMax = {{xPos - range, 
    xPos + range}, {f[xPos] - range*GoldenRatio^-1, 
    f[xPos] + range*GoldenRatio^-1}};

Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 10}, {-2, 15}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 17/12, 
 Epilog -> {Transparent, EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], 
   Rectangle[Sequence @@ Transpose[xyMinMax]], 
   Inset[Plot[f[x], {x, xPos - range, xPos + range}, Frame -> True, 
     FrameStyle -> Red, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> xyMinMax, 
     ImageSize -> 200], {6, 5}]}, ImageSize -> 350, 
 PlotLabel -> "f(x)=εφ(x)", GridLines -> {{Pi/2}, None}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[-Pi, 3 Pi, Pi/2], Automatic}]


Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance!

see how-to-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-plot there are solutions there that do not use Gridlines

@Nasser I had seen it, but trying to combine two things in one Epilog either filled me with errors or produced nothing. Anyway, I just found the solution. Thanks for your time regardless.

Oops! I found the solution and it was obvious! Sorry for the inconvenience...
Clear["Global`*"]
xPos = 1.502;
range = 0.2;
f[x_] := Tan[x];
xyMinMax = {{xPos - range, 
    xPos + range}, {f[xPos] - range*GoldenRatio^-1, 
    f[xPos] + range*GoldenRatio^-1}};

Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 10}, {-2, 15}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 17/12, 
 Epilog -> {Transparent, EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], 
   Rectangle[Sequence @@ Transpose[xyMinMax]], 
   Inset[Plot[f[x], {x, xPos - range, xPos + range}, Frame -> True, 
     FrameStyle -> Red, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> xyMinMax, 
     ImageSize -> 200, GridLines -> {{Pi/2}, None}], {6, 5}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 350, PlotLabel -> "f(x)=εφ(x)", 
 GridLines -> {{Pi/2}, None}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[-Pi, 3 Pi, Pi/2], Automatic}]

